# Writing to Email column using Notion-API

Tags: notion-api

I have been trying to write to an Email column in my database but I keep
getting this error.

The column has a property type of email

```
Email has a value that does not match its property type: email.
```

I'm making the request using the Notion Api through Insomnia by making a POST request
to `https://api.notion.com/v1/pages`. This is
how the body looks like.

```json
{
    "parent": {
        "database_id": "a_long_database_id"
    },
    "properties": {
        "Email": {
            "email": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "content": "someebody@gmail.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is coming from the properties but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the column in your database is set to email. Then for email the format looks off in your request. Try this:

```
        "Email": {
        "email": "somebody@email.com"
       }
```